# smtplib doesn't fail on invalid email addresses

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib, django-email

In django, I tried sending  a  mail using `send_mail` like :

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail("test", "test", settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ["sasdadome@asdijandasd.com"])
```

This surprisingly sends me a status of `1`, which means it was delivered successfully .

If I try sending the same using my gmail account, I get a failure response immediately.

How do I catch such failures with `smtplib` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This email adress is very valid. It just doesn't exist. Neither django nor smtplib verify whether a domain exists. They just deliver the mail to an MTA which reacts appropiately.

Comment: great. Any workaround for this ? Do you suggest any other library for python ? :)

Comment: you want to immediately (more or less) check whether an email address exists? That would be a spammers wet dream... you can check whether a domain exists by `dig` or `nslookup` (shell) or in python `socket.gethostbyname()`

Comment: haha. Great. I think I am gonna try postmark. Lets see if that helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Smtplib only check email address format and smtp server (gmail in your case) queue the messages and return ok